# How can I record a demonstration to use with Proximal Policy Optimization?

Tags: unity, machine-learning

I have a fuzzy logic controller for my race car that works fairly well. I want to use a recording of this as a demonstration for the PPO (Proximal Policy Optimization) algorithm from ML Agents for the same race car.

Do I set the fuzzy logic algorithm in the heuristic method of my Agent implementation?  The documentation is very vague.

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate that you implement the control logic in the [Heuristic](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ml-agents@1.0/api/Unity.MLAgents.Agent.html#Unity_MLAgents_Agent_Heuristic_System_Single___) function and then use a [DemonstrationRecorder](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/release_2_verified_docs/docs/Learning-Environment-Design-Agents.md#recording-demonstrations) to record the `.demo` file. How have you tried putting this into practice so far and where has the behaviour differed from what you need?